# Is there a way to display a pandas Dataframe in KivyMD?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, kivymd

Is there a way to display a pandas DataFrame in KivyMD? I tried putting the dataframe as a KivyMD DataTable but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the MDDataTable and fill the row with the dataframe. You only need to process the data. Try to define a function to do that:

```
def get_data_table(dataframe):
    column_data = list(dataframe.columns)
    row_data = dataframe.to_records(index=False)
    return column_data, row_data
```

Then you can put all into the MDDataTable after setting the size of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp

dataframe  = pd.read_csv(filename)
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):

        layout = AnchorLayout()
        
        
        container = my_root.ids.container
        print(container)
        column_data, row_data = get_data_table(dataframe)
        column_data = [(x, dp(60)) for x in column_data]

        table = MDDataTable(
            column_data = column_data,
            row_data = row_data,
            use_pagination=True
        )
        layout.add_widget(table)
        
        return layout
MyApp().run()
```